# Why does explicit typecasting allow upcasting for private inheritance?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
    void f(){cout<<"A"<<endl;}
};

class B : private A {
    public:
    void f(){cout<<"B"<<endl;}
};

int main (){
```

As Class B is inheriting Class A privately, this upcasting is not supposed to work:

```
    A* a = new B;
```

But explicit typecasting is allowing it.
Why?

```
    A* a1 = (A*)new B;
    a1->f();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The c-cast allows most conversion (even from `int*` into `A*`). The usage then might be UB with expected output.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925124/can-i-cast-a-derived-class-to-a-private-base-class-c

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The cast in

```
A* a1 = (A*)new B;
```

is a cast to inaccessible base class.

It can only be expressed as a C style cast. It is equivalent to what a `static_cast` would do if a `static_cast` could be used in this situation, and it is not equivalent to a `reinterpret_cast`. In particular the result address is not necessarily the same as the argument address.

**C++11 §5.4/4:**

> **”**  The same semantic restrictions and behaviors [as for a `static_cast`] apply [for a C style cast], with the exception that in performing a `static_cast` in the following situations the conversion is valid even if the base class is inaccessible:
>
> — a pointer to an object of derived class type or an lvalue or rvalue of derived class type may be explicitly converted to a pointer or reference to an unambiguous base class type, respectively;

Comment: If it can't be expressed in terms of reinterpret_cast and const_cast, it's not a valid cast at all.

Comment: @RichardHodges: Cast to inaccessible base class, and `dynamic_cast`, and even `static_cast` for the general case, can't be expressed in terms of `reinterpret_cast` and `const_cast`. I.e. your statement that “If it can't be expressed in terms of reinterpret_cast and const_cast, it's not a valid cast at all.” is a nonsense assertion. Sorry.

Comment: I see the reference and stand corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

This is allowed by the rules of C-style casts:

> (N3337) `[expr.cast]/4`: The conversions performed by
>
> - a const_cast (5.2.11),
> - a static_cast (5.2.9),
> - a static_cast followed by a const_cast,
> - a reinterpret_cast (5.2.10), or
> - a reinterpret_cast followed by a const_cast,
>
> can be performed using the cast notation of explicit type conversion. The same semantic restrictions
>   and behaviors apply, **with the exception that in performing a static_cast in the following situations the conversion is valid even if the base class is inaccessible**:
>
> - **a pointer to an object of derived class type or an lvalue or rvalue of derived class type may be explicit
>     converted to a pointer or reference to an unambiguous base class type, respectively;**
> - [...]

If you change to a `static_cast`, then this will fail to compile. GCC gives this error:

```
error: 'A' is an inaccessible base of 'B'
    A* a1 = static_cast<A*>(new B);
```

Answer (score 5):

Explicit casting allow you to do everything you want. You can, for example, to write so:

```
int *p = (int*)new B;
```

and the code will be compiled.
Explicit cast means that you know what you are doing.

Comment: *Explicit cast means that you know what you are doing.* => usually the opposite.  :-)

Comment: Explicit cast tells the compiler that "I know what I'm doing"

Comment: My compiler is more convinced when I tell it `-Wold-style-cast`.

Comment: @Alexey Subbota - "Explicit cast tells the compiler that "I know what I'm doing"  - it rather says: I know that maybe i  am doing wrong thing, but you should do it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The explicit typecasting is a programming feature of C language which doesn't have any object orientation features or rules. For C language everything is pointers (to memory or functions). Updcasting and downcasting are object orientation features provided by c++. The inheritance casting must behave on the object orientation rules of the language.  However, by typecasting the object like this: `A* a1 = (A*)new B;` you force 
the compiler to treat the object as `A` just as you would do in C by forcing a pointer of a struct to another. Therefore, when the compiler decides which function pointer to assign on the `f()` calling pointer of the casted object it assigns the pointer of the `A` class implementation.

Comment: I think this is the most relevant answer since the op asks why.