# Difference among three explicit upcasting to a private base class

Tags: c++, typecasting-operator, private-inheritance

I have the following three typecastings between the private inherited base class object and the child object, two of them work, but the last one doesn't. I am wondering what causes the different results.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class test :private string
{
public:
    test(string st) :string(st){}
    void show();
};

void test::show()
{
    cout << (string)*this << endl; // typecasting 1, works, display "abcd"
}
int main()
{
    test a("abcd");
    a.show();

    cout << (string &)a << endl; //typecasting 2, works, display "abcd"

    cout<<(string )a<<endl;   //typecasting 3;  error C2243: 'type cast' : conversion from 'test *' to 'const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &' exists, but is inaccessible     
}
```

Isn't `a` the same as '*this' - since both are objects? So why does No.1 work?
If it's because of scope, then why No.2 works? Could anyone please explain the mechanism behind each of them that make the difference among them?

Also, the first method seems to create a string object. In the private inherited case, base class reference can't be set to the derived class object.  So how the temporary string object is created?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot really do inheritance casting with direct values. This usually only works with pointers and references. `*this` is a `const&` thats why it "works" here. same for `string &`. But you cannot really cast one type into another with using direct values. I am also not sure if your casts have some negative side effects at some point (casting a ref to a value and vice versa). Also for others: I understand that this is test code but please do not code like that in real projects ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot. May I ask how the temporary string obj is created when base class reference can't be set to the derived class object? Does it secretly treat `*this` as the reference to a base class when we do the explicit upcasting? Also, I won't do this in a real project :) I came across it by a typo..

Comment: You mentioned `*this` is a `const &` type. Could you please point me to some reference. I am sorry I looked it up but didn't find the relevant info (possibly because the key words are too widely used.) Thanks

Comment: Figures I was not 100% correct there. this is only a const ptr in a const function. so in this case it's just a normal pointer and dereferencing it would result in a normal reference. The * operator usually returns a reference to the object. But I can't really point you to anything written that defines this now sadly :(

Comment: I was surprised that dereferencing a pointer results in a reference. I thought it resulted in the variable/object. No problem. I'll look for it. Thanks~

Comment: I tested it: http://cpp.sh/6du4 does not copy (if i replace `auto&` with `auto` though it does)

Comment: Wow, that's very surprising. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test` subclasses `string` privately, so `test` "knows" it is a `string`, but anyone outside doesn't.

In your first case, what happens is as follows:

1. Outside of `test` (in `main`), you call the `show` method. That's OK, because it's public.
2. Now, inside `show`, the code "knows" it's of type `string`, because it's a method of `test`. The conversion is OK.

In your third case, though, you're trying to do the conversion outside, from `main`. Outside of `test`, `main` "doesn't know" that `test` is a `string`.

How does your second case work, then? You're performing a [C-style cast from a derived to public base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925124/can-i-cast-a-derived-class-to-a-private-base-class-using-c-style-cast). Surprisingly, this is allowed (although not necessarily good style!). Quoting from the accepted answer there: §5.4/7 of the standard:

> ... the following static_cast and reinterpret_cast operations (optionally followed by a const_cast operation) may be performed using the cast notation of explicit type conversion, even if the base class type is not accessible: a pointer to an object of derived class type or an lvalue of derived class type may be explicitly converted to a pointer or reference to an unambiguous base class type, respectively;

Comment: Thanks a lot. May I ask how the temporary string obj is created when base class reference can't be set to the derived class object?  Is it also because inside the 'test' class, they know the inheritance so the base class reference can be set to a private derived class object?

Comment: @FlowingCloud Are you talking about the first case?

Comment: @FlowingCloud Within the `show` method, though, `test` is a perfectly valid `string` object too (this is what private inheritance means). So the code means "cast the `string` part of `*this` to a `string`". Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, perfectly. Thank you a lot.