# Why a friend class member can access a private member of the class it is being friend to through an object of publicly inherited class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend, access-specifier

As we know a `private` member is inaccessible (not just private) in derived classes while `public` and `protected` are directly accessible there.

- If a class declares another class as a `friend` then the latter has full-access to the members of the first.

Here is an example I've tried to understand but in vain:

```
class A
{
    public:
       int pub;
    private:
       int priv;
    protected:
        int prot;
    friend class D;
};

class B : public A // public inheritance
{
    int b = 0;
};

class C : private A
{
    int c = 0;

};

class D
{
     public:
        void foo(B);
        void bar(C);
};

void D::foo(B b)
{
    b.pub = 0;
    b.prot = 0;
    b.priv = 0; // why this works? although A::priv is inaccessible in derived classes because it is private in base class?
   // b.b = 0; // error. ok because b is private
}

void D::bar(C c)
{
 //   c.pub = 0; // error ok
 //   c.prot = 0; // error ok
 //   c.priv = 0; // error ok
 //   c.c = 0; // error. ok because c is private
}
```

- The problem: Why `D::foo` can access private member of `A` through an object from a `public`ly inherited from Base `A` although we know `private` is inaccessible in derived classes? so why `b.priv = 0;` works? We know that `friendship` is neither transitive nor inherited?

Comment: *"We know that friendship is neither transitive nor inherited?"* - Your example doesn't violate that. Only the `A` part is being accessed.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: But why instances of B in D's member functions can access even private members of A while instances of C cannot? I guess this has a relation to type of inheritance. can you explain? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`class D` is friend of `class A`, it has full access to its *public*, *protected* and *private* members. `class B` `public`ly inherit `class A`, that means, `class D` has access<sup>1)</sup> to base class of `class B`. Hence, the access of `priv` member of `class A` using object of `class B` is allowed in `class D`.

---

Read below part of answer only if you are thinking that access of `pub`, `prot` and `priv`, in `D::bar(C)` function of friend class `D`, is giving error because `class A` is `private`ly inherited by `class C`.

In case of `class C`, it `private`ly inherit `class A`. As you have pointed out that the statements `c.pub`, `c.prot` and `c.priv` of `D::bar(C)` function are giving error. It's because of `class C` inherit `class A` `private`ly.

If I uncomment them and compile, the errors I am getting in `D::bar(C)` function are:

```
p.cpp:44:5: error: cannot cast 'C' to its private base class 'A'
    c.pub = 0;
    ^
p.cpp:21:11: note: declared private here
class C : private A
          ^~~~~~~~~
p.cpp:44:7: error: 'pub' is a private member of 'A'
    c.pub = 0;
      ^
p.cpp:21:11: note: constrained by private inheritance here
class C : private A
          ^~~~~~~~~
p.cpp:8:12: note: member is declared here
       int pub;
```

Same errors for `prot` and `priv` members as well.

These errors are due to `private` inheritance of `class A` and **has nothing to do** with friend `class D`. Try access it in similar way outside of friend `class D` and you will get same errors.

Using C style cast you can [cast a derived class to private base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925124/can-i-cast-a-derived-class-to-a-private-base-class-using-c-style-cast), like this:

```
void D::bar(C c)
{
    ((A*)&c)->pub = 0;
    ((A*)&c)->prot = 0;
    ((A*)&c)->priv = 0;
    //c.c = 0; // error. ok because c is private
}
```

With this now you can access `class C` `private`ly inherit base class (`class A`) private members in its friend class `class D`.
Note that `priv` member access using C style cast in `D::bar(C)` function is **working fine** only because `class D` is friend of `class A`.
If you try to access the private member of `private`ly inherit base class in derived class using C style cast, its not allowed:

```
class C : private A {
    int c = 0;
    public:
      void Cfoo();

};

void C::Cfoo() {
        ((A*)this)->pub = 100;
        ((A*)this)->priv = 100;   // error: 'priv' is a private member of 'A'
}
```

---

1).
Quoting from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance/860353#860353) answer:

Let's consider a class `Base` and a class `Child` that inherits from `Base`.

- If the inheritance is `public`, everything that is aware of `Base` and
  `Child` is also aware that `Child` inherits from `Base`.
- If the inheritance is `protected`, only `Child`, and its children, are
  aware that they inherit from `Base`.
- If the inheritance is `private`, no one other than `Child` is aware of
  the inheritance.